# Is there any way to prevent useless renders?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, performance

I have performance problem, i have array of arrays when user searches in input whole array of arrays changes and renders all of the data again, but only one array must change on search and only one array must render again, is there any way to track these arrays and update only one of them?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js">

  //search checkbox items
  const checkboxSearch = () => {
  //this is array of arrays
    let tempVar = [...uniques];
  //containerID is index of selected array
    const results = props.unique[containerID].filter((item) => {
    //you can ignore this its just regular search
      if (item) {
        if (typeof item !== "number") {
          return item.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        } else {
          return (
            item.toString().indexOf(searchValue.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1
          );
        }
      }
      return null;
    });
  //...
  //im updating only changed array
  //..
    tempVar[containerID] = results;
    //and setting whole array again(this is problem)
   //couse of this whole headers re-renders again
    setUniques(tempVar);
  };

</script>
```

parent array render method:

```html
{uniques.map((uniqueData, index) => {
            return (
              <th key={index}>
                <div className="searchContainerWrapper">
                  <div className="searchBox">
                    <div id={index} className="options">
                      
                      <TableHead
                        index={index}
                        keys={props.keys}
                        tableSearch={(e) => tableSearch(e)}
                        handleCheckbox={(e) => handleCheckbox(e)}
                        unique={uniqueData}
                        ifAnyChecked={(e) => ifAnyChecked(e)}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <button>
                    <SearchIcon />
                  </button>
                </div>
              </th>
            );
          })}
```

and child arrays render (one of them will be updated),
this is

```html
 {props.unique.map((item, key) => {
        return (
          <label
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.stopPropagation();
              props.ifAnyChecked(e);
            }}
            onFocus={() => console.log(props.index)}
            key={key}
          >
            <input
              onClick={(e) => {
                props.tableSearch(e);
              }}
              type="checkbox"
              value={item ? item : "empty"}
            />
            {item && item.length > 24 ? (
              props.handleCheckbox(item)
            ) : (
              <p>
                {item && typeof item === "number"
                  ? numberWithCommas(item.toFixed(2))
                  : item}
              </p>
            )}
          </label>
        );
      })}
```

any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] with a complete component, please?

Comment: Please show us where and how you are rendering the `uniques` state

Comment: its usual render from variable uniques im making map and rendering them like ==> unique.map((item,key) => return <p key={key}>{item}</p>

Comment: But you say it's an array of arrays - a single `map` won't render them?

Comment: no im doing double map maping columns and then maping data inside columns

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code of that

Comment: @Bergi sorry, i already edited